# CallBack on garbagecollected Delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, callback, dllimport

I'm working with a usb device. This Device receives messages and I don't know when or how often. The API that comes with the driver specifies a setreceiveCallBack function that gives a callback when the device receives a message.
But at random times or intervals I receive a callback on garbagecollected delegate exeption. I have searched for solutions to my problem but none of the solutions seem to work in my case.
The following is the biggest part of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallBacktesting
{
    public unsafe delegate void callBack(Form1.CANMsg *pmsg);

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        uint handle;
        static WriteLog log = new WriteLog();
        Boolean getCan = false;
        static int frameCount = 0;
        static CANMsg newmsg = new CANMsg();
        callBack _setCallBack;
        List<string> write = new List<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void buttonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                // Open connection
        }

        private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               // Close connection
        }

        private void buttonCallBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!getCan)
            {
                int rv;
                unsafe
                {
                    callBack _setCallBack = new callBack(call);
                    rv = canusb_setReceiveCallBack(handle, _setCallBack);
                }
                label1.Text = rv.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                _setCallBack = null;
                int rv = canusb_setReceiveCallBack(handle, _setCallBack);
                GC.KeepAlive(_setCallBack);
                label1.Text = rv.ToString();
            }
        }

        public unsafe void call(CANMsg *pmsg)
        {
            newmsg = *pmsg;
            update();
        }

        private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GC.KeepAlive(_setCallBack);
            Application.Exit();
        }

        [DllImport("canusbdrv.dll", EntryPoint = "canusb_setReceiveCallBack")]
        public static extern int canusb_setReceiveCallBack(uint handle, callBack callBack);

        unsafe private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              // update the form with received messages
        }

        public void update()
        {
            CANMsg msgrec = newmsg;
            // Build str from messages with all data
            write.Add(str);
            log.logWrite(str);
            frameCount++;
        }
    }

    public class WriteLog
    {

        private void OpenFile()
        {     }

        public void logWrite(string log)
        {     }

        public void logAdd(string log)
        {     }

        private void logClose()
        {     }
    }
}
```

Comment: I remove some code for readability and corrected the error (used _setCallBack instead of setCallBack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, when you do

```
                callBack setCallBack = new callBack(call);
                rv = canusb_setReceiveCallBack(handle, call);
```

the delegate will be available for garbage collection after you invoke 'canusb_setReceiveCallBack' because no where in your code is the delegate referenced.

You could avoid this be storing it in a private field.

E.x.:

```
Class Form1
{

callBack _setCallBack;

private void buttonCallBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


                _setCallBack = new callBack(call);
                rv = canusb_setReceiveCallBack(handle, _setCallBack);

}

}
```

But this may have some problems because each button click will create a new callback. This can be problematic if the previous callback needed to be referenced.

I think what you should do is refactor the code to use a [SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) to store the handle returned by canusb_Open.

I would design the class like this.

```
class CanUsbSafeHandle : SafeHandle
{
    private EventHandler _receiveCallBack;
    private readonly object _receiveCallBackLock = new object();

    public event EventHandler ReceiveCallBack
    {
        add
        {
            lock (_receiveCallBackLock)
            {
                bool hasListeners = (_receiveCallBack != null);
                _receiveCallBack += value;
                //call canusb_setReceiveCallBack only when 1 or more listeners were added
                //and there were previously no listeners
                if (!hasListeners && (_receiveCallBack != null))
                {
                    canusb_setReceiveCallBack(this, setCallBack);
                }
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (_receiveCallBackLock)
            {
                bool hasListeners = (_receiveCallBack != null);
                _receiveCallBack -= value;
                //call canusb_setReceiveCallBack only when there are no more listeners.
                if(hasListeners && (_receiveCallBack == null))
                {
                    canusb_setReceiveCallBack(this, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public CanUsbSafeHandle()
        : base(IntPtr.Zero, true)
    {
    }

    public override bool IsInvalid
    {
        get { return handle == IntPtr.Zero; }
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return canusb_Close(handle);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            lock (_receiveCallBackLock)
            {
                _receiveCallBack = null;
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

That way, the SafeHandle will manage the 'receive callback' delegate's lifetime will be managed by the SafeHandle.

Comment: Kragen pointed out something I missed, and that is, 'call' is being passed in instead of 'setCallBack'.

Comment: oke I adjusted the setCallBack to a private field and restored the _setCallBack being passed in stead of call.
Because the program should only use 1 CallBack I'm not trying your Safehandle suggestion for now (And I'm not sure I really understand it).
going to test it now

Comment: Thank you very much. Just as simple as a private field seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Is this correct / a typo?:

```
callBack setCallBack = new callBack(call);
rv = canusb_setReceiveCallBack(handle, call);
```

You appear to create an instance of callBack, but then pass something else to `canusb_setReceiveCallBack` - did you mean to pass `setCallBack` instead?

Also, on this line you are declaring setCallBack to be a local variable, and so even if you do pass `setCallBack` instead of `call`, you are still passing a locally scoped variable which will probably be garbage collected (I noticed that you do `GC.KeepAlive(setCallBack);`
 to explicitly prevent this)

Comment: I tried both. I was not sure if I had to pass setCallBack or could pass the funtion itself. But it did not seem to make any difference, both give the exception.
I also declared setCallBack at the beginning to make it alive during the lifetime of my application.